# can Database handle simultaneous updates or writes?

Tags: database, thread-safety, connection-pooling

I was just trying to figure out ,can Database operations be performed in parallel.
Suppose one database is shared among multiple applications, each doing update operation, may be same row. In that case can database be in right state once all operations are done.
I am not talking about the multiple threads in single application , they are all separate application.
Even in multithreaded application, if we use connection pooling, each thread having its own connection, all those threads will be allowed to update data simultaneously and can disturb the the Database state ...

I am confused . did not find any viable explanation on this.

Thanks

Comment: It is already being done. For eg: read about MySQL replication

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Replication is a different solution to a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called ACID , the database guaranty Atomicy, Consistency, Isolation and Durability.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)

Comment: so basically , its database's headache to deal with these kind of things... applications can do the database operations in whichever way they want ..

Comment: ACID properties comes when it involves transaction.. but what if the operation getting done are non transactional...

Comment: In this case any insert, update or delete is threated as an single transation. So You can be sure that no other thread will mess in data during this operation. When the operation is finished anything can happen. Updating table and rows by many different applications will not break the database. But You can't expect that between selecting some row and updating it a second later someone haven't deleted it or updated.